# How do I make the sveltekit app send the correct date from the server to the client using prisma?

Tags: date, datetime, svelte, sveltekit

I am using Prisma in my sveltekit app to get my data. I have the model below. All of the datetime of type @db.DateTime from the database are returning correctly. All of the shift_date of type @db.Date are subtracting one day from what is stored in my database on the client side but not the server side. The format of the database is type Date and is in this format "YYYY-MM-DD". My server is returning shift_date: 2022-03-15T00:00:00.000Z but when I console log what the client has it is showing shift_date: Mon Mar 14 2022 20:00:00 GMT-0. I am pretty sure that the client is just converting the date wrong. I am not sure the best solution. Can I somehow format the date to my local timezone before I send it to the client? Otherwise on the client side every time I use this date I will need to add a day which I would rather not do.

My models:

```
model TurnReport {
  entry_id   Int      @id(map: "PK_TurnReport") @default(autoincrement())
  comment    String   @db.Text
  datetime   DateTime @db.DateTime
  author     String?  @db.VarChar(100)
  area_id    Int
  shift_date DateTime @db.Date
  shift_num  Int      @db.TinyInt
  ip         String?  @db.VarChar(32)
  TurnReport_Attachments TurnReport_Attachments[] 
}

model TurnReport_Areas {
  area_id          Int              @id(map: "PK_TurnReport_Areas")
  name             String           @db.VarChar(75)
  dept_id          Int
  enabled          Boolean
  sort_order       Int
  has_stars        Boolean
  TurnReport_Depts TurnReport_Depts @relation(fields: [dept_id], references: [dept_id], onDelete: Cascade, map: "FK_TurnReport_Areas_TurnReport_Depts")
  vTurnReport vTurnReport[]
}

model TurnReport_Attachments {
  attachment_id  Int      @id(map: "PK_TurnReport_Attachments") @default(autoincrement())
  entry_id       Int
  file_name      String   @db.NVarChar(255)
  datetime       DateTime @db.DateTime
  content_type   String   @db.NVarChar(255)
  content_length Int
  data_blob      Bytes
  TurnReport TurnReport @relation(fields: [entry_id], references: [entry_id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

My query:

```
export async function load({ params, getClientAddress }) {

    const allData = await prisma.TurnReport_Depts.findUnique({
        where: {
            dept_id: parseInt(params.dept)
        },
        include: {
            TurnReport_Areas: {
                where: {
                    dept_id: parseInt(params.dept)
                },
                include: {
                    vTurnReport: {
                        where: {
                            shift_date: params.date + 'T00:00:00.000Z',
                            shift_num: parseInt(params.shift)
                        },
                        include: {
                            vTurnReport_Attachments: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })

    
    await prisma.$disconnect()
    console.log(allData)
```

The server console log"

```
entry_id: 467,
      comment: '...',
      datetime: 2022-03-15T18:51:54.843Z,
      author: 'Sam, Tim',
      area_id: 140,
      shift_date: 2022-03-15T00:00:00.000Z,
      shift_num: 1,
      ip: '10.39.12.27',
      attachment_count: 0,
      vTurnReport_Attachments: []
```

The client console log:

```
area_id: 140
attachment_count: 0
author: "Sam, Tim"
comment: "..."
datetime: Tue Mar 15 2022 14:51:54 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {}
entry_id: 467
ip: "10.39.12.27"
shift_date: Mon Mar 14 2022 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {}
shift_num: 1
vTurnReport_Attachments: []
```

Comment: I have just noticed that it is taking 4 hours off of each date and datetime. I know it's not accounting for the timezone change but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it when it sends from the server to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that I am able to use. I made functions that will convert the date/times recieved from my prisma client and added them to a file called prismaFunction.js. And then anywhere I use dates from prisma or send dates to prisma I import the functions. I used date-fns for these functions. These functions account for daylight savings time.

```
//functions used to fix prisma datetime if database times are not being saved in UTC

import { format } from 'date-fns';

//fixed datetimes sent to database if database times are not in UTC
export function fixedDateToPrisma(date) {
    return format(date, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
};

//fix timezone issue from prisma if database times are not in utc
export function fixedDateFromPrisma(date) {
    return new Date(date.substring(0, date.length - 1));
};
```

Here is an example of how I would send a date to prisma. Here I am getting my date from the url request and then sending the fixed date to the server.

```
import { fixedDateToPrisma } from '../../../prismaFunctions';

/** @type {import('./$types').RequestHandler} */
export async function PUT({ request }) {
    try {
        const { alertId, modalComment, modalDeptId } = await request.json();
        await prisma.TurnReport_Alerts.update({
            where: {
                alert_id: alertId
            },
            data: {
                alert_comment: modalComment,
                dt_updated: fixedDateToPrisma(new Date()),
            }
        })
        await prisma.$disconnect()
        return json()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: error.message }), { status: 500 });
    }
}
```

And here is an example of using it inside a component where I am getting the date and converting it. In my case I am getting it from props but it will work the same if you are getting if from your fetch call. I hope this helps anyone else having the same problem!

```
<script>
     export let data;
     import {fixedDateFromPrisma} from '../prismaFunctions'

</script>

<h1>Date: {fixedDateFromPrisma(data.date)}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the correct answer

---

The 'Z' at the end of your DateTime string signifies that the time is in UTC.

<strike>Simply removing it from `'T00:00:00.000Z'` will make JS parse it in it's local time zone.</strike>

```js
new Date("2023-04-01T00:00Z");
// Sat Apr 01 2023 02:00:00 GMT+0200

new Date("2023-04-01T00:00");
// Sat Apr 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

Comment: If you're referring to shift_date: params.date + 'T00:00:00.000Z', params.date is a string. I can do new Date(params.date) which returns a date. But it gives me the same result. The timezone the server receives is Z timeszone. So I guess is there a way to tell prisma that the times it is receiving is in a different timezone other than Z?

Comment: A little more information that may be relevent, this is an existing database that is used by other apps and the timezone is eastern on the database.

Comment: @Avi4nFLu My bad, I don't use Prisma and I didn't notice that was a where clause. You could just manually alter the date before it gets serialized or set the server to be in UTC. That is pretty bad though and there should be a better solution. Sorry I can't help